# java timestamp conversion

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I have two programs but I cannot find a way to merge the two of them together. Is there anyway I can do this?

This is the fisrt part of code by converting the date to a string

```
package main_program;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;

public class testing2 {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy ");
        String time = " Wed Dec 14 00:00:00 CST 2012 ";
        Date date = null; 
        try {
            date = format.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Format To times:"); 
            System.out.println(date.getTime());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the second part of the code by converting the string in long to a formated date

```
package main_program;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class lta {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Date ABC= new java.util.Date(1355241600000l);
        System.out.println(new Timestamp(ABC.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: The first snippet converts a `String` to a `Date`. The second one creates a `Date` from an integer, and a `Timestamp` from that `Date`. What do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: combining the two to convert the string to timestamp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main_program;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class testing2 {
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(" EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy ");
        String time = " Wed Dec 14 00:00:00 CST 2012 ";
        Date date = null; 
        try {
            date = format.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            System.out.println("Format To times:"); 
            System.out.println(date.getTime());
            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
            System.out.println(ts);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To merge them together, you could instead of defining two main methods in separate classes, create a single larger class with the given methods defined.  The methods should probably be set to return values, rather than printing, in that case.  You could print the values returned from them, if you so desire.  Something like this:

Modified to accomplish the goal stated in comments:

```
public class MyClass {
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Do whatever you are intending to, calling 'lta' and 'testing2', like:
        String time=" Wed Dec 14 00:00:00 CST 2012 ";
        long longtime = testing2(time);
        System.out.println(lta(longtime));
    }

    public static Timestamp lta(long time)
    {
        java.util.Date ABC= new java.util.Date(time);
        return new Timestamp(ABC.getTime());
    }

    public static long testing2(String time)    {
        SimpleDateFormat format =   new SimpleDateFormat( " EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy " );
        Date date = null; 
        try {
            date = format.parse(time);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return String.valueOf(date.getTime());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```